# Which set of chords through a unit circle minimizes the largest demarcated area?

Tags: geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $A_n$ be the minimum possible largest area inside a unit circle traced by $n$ lines.

A circle can be divided into $\frac{n^2+n+2}2$ regions by tracing $n$ chords, so $A_n\geq\frac{2\pi}{n^2+n+2}$ is an easy lower bound. By making the chords all evenly spaced diameters we get $A_n\leq \frac \pi {2n}$ but I get the feeling that this is very loose and $A_n$ will be closer to the lower bound for large n.

For $n=1,2$ the lower bound is easily achieved, but for $n=3$ it is difficult to beat the upper bound $\frac\pi 6$.

[image]

In a symmetrical arrangement like this the area of the three large outside sections is always $\geq\pi/6$, so if there's a better arrangement it must not have triangular symmetry. In fact I think this is the case for all $n\geq 3$.

So what can be said about $A_n$? I conjecture that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2A_n<\infty$$

But beyond that I find it difficult to determine anything about it.

Comment: So your triangle arrangement can be generalised to $n$ chords by saying we want a regular $n$-gon in the middle, such that if we extend all the sides of the $n$-gon to become chords, the largest region outside the $n$-gon has the same area as the $n$-gon itself. It looks like a decent solution, but I have no idea what the relevant areas become, and whether it's optimal.

Comment: I think you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 A_n < \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By taking $n/2$ equally spaced horizontal and $n/2$ equally spaced vertical lines, the regions all have area $\le (2/(n/2+1))^2= O(1/n^2)$.

Comment: It looks like this is the optimal arrangement for $n>3$.